# Dynamically creating URL in javascript based on user input

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, url-parameters

I am trying to create a URL dynamically based on the user selection

so I wrote js like this:

```
getPatientProfile(patient, relative, relation, contactNumber, townCity) {

    var p = patient.trim()
    var r = relative.trim()

    var url = 'http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patient/profile?patient=' + p + '&relative=' + r ;

    if (relation != null || relation != "" || relation != undefined){
        url += "&relationType=" + relation;
    }
    if (contactNumber != null || contactNumber != ""){
        url += "&contactNumber=" + contactNumber;
    }
    if (townCity != null || townCity != ""){
        url += "&townCity=" + townCity;
    }
    return axios.get(url);
}
```

but I am still getting the whole URL: `http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patient/profile?patient=vernacular&relative=Dreams&relationType=undefined&contactNumber=&townCity=`

what I want if relation, contactNumber and townCity is not given by user the url should just be `http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patient/profile?patient=vernacular&relative=Dreams`

Comment: your boolean logic is off - you need to ensure all the conditions are satisfied instead of any of the conditions are satisfied, i.e. change all `||` to `&&`

Comment: And you don't need to check all the falsey value explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when a user does not give any value then it's always conditioning true.
  townCity != null and  relation != null and contactNumber != null

```
function getPatientProfile(patient, relative, relation, contactNumber, townCity) 
{

var p = patient.trim()
var r = relative.trim()

var url = 'http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patient/profile?patient=' + p + '&relative=' + r ;

if (relation != null && relation != "" && relation != undefined){
    url += "&relationType=" + relation;
}
if (contactNumber != null && contactNumber != ""){
    url += "&contactNumber=" + contactNumber;
}
if (townCity != null && townCity != ""){
    url += "&townCity=" + townCity;
}
return axios.get(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` when you want all the condition to be true.

Or you don't even need to check all the falsey value explicity

```js
function getPatientProfile(patient, relative, relation, contactNumber, townCity) {

    var p = patient.trim()
    var r = relative.trim()

    var url = 'http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patient/profile?patient=' + p + '&relative=' + r ;

    if (relation){
        url += "&relationType=" + relation;
    }
    if (contactNumber){
        url += "&contactNumber=" + contactNumber;
    }
    if (townCity){
        url += "&townCity=" + townCity;
    }
    return url
}

console.log(getPatientProfile('rel','pat'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make `getPatientProfile(patient, relative, relation, contactNumber, townCity)` more generic if you go by json way :

```
var keys = {
patient : "Thor",
relative : "Loki",
relation : "Brothers",
contactNumber : null,
townCity : ""
};
function getPatientProfile(options){
var url = 'http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patient/profile';
  for (key in options){ 
     var separator = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
     if(!!options[key]){ //checks for the truthy condition of the options[key]
        options[key] = options[key].trim(); //you can also add conditions for the keys which you want to trim.
        url += separator + key + "=" + options[key];
     }
  }
return url;
}
```

this way you can add/remove keys easily :)